# Increase value variable bash

Tags: bash, variables

I want to increase the var upPCs by one every time I go through the if statement.

```
upPCs= 0;

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

$upPCs ++;

fi
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: You can use: `((upPCs++))` in bash.

Comment: You can try `upPCs=$upPCs+1;`

Comment: On a side note: don't put spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Bash (and other shells) do not allow spaces around the equals sign.  A semi-colon ; is used to separate commands on a line, so putting one at the end of the line is a waste (unless your really enjoy typing semi-colons...).

```
upPCs=0
```

Use `(( ))` for arithmetics:

```
if (( $? == 0 )); then

    (( upPCs++ ))

fi
```

Finally, you should indent your code inside `if` (and `while`, `for`, etc) statements, because if you don't a kitten dies.  Seriously, scripts can get unreadable quite quickly if you do not indent - it is worth it.

By the way, often you don't need to test `$?` explicitly.  You don't show the command that you are testing the result of, but the principle is that `if` is true if the command is successful (exit code of zero is considered success).  For example:

```
if some_command
then
    (( upPCs++ ))
fi
```